# One Liner - Dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, data-structures

I am migrating neo4j to sql in batches. I want to have the following data structure:

```
[{key1_1: value1_1, key1_2: value1_2}, {key2_1: value2_1, key2_2: value2_2}, etc}]
```

I have the following line of code that parses the result of the neo4j query:

```
data = [{r.__dict__['_keys']: r.__dict__['_values']} for r in result]
```

However, this return the data as:

```
[{(key1_1, key1_2): (value1_1, value1_2)}, {(key2_1, key2_2): (value2_1, value2_2)}, etc]
```

How do I wrangle the data in a nice one liner, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to zip up the keys and values, and pass those to a `dict()` call, no dict comprehensions required:

```
data = [dict(zip(r._keys, r._values)) for r in result]
```

Here, each `dict()` call produces a new dictionary from the `(key, value)` pairs that `zip()` outputs

I didn't access `__dict__` directly here, using the `_keys` and `_values` attributes should suffice.

Demo:

```
>>> class Record(object):
...     def __init__(self, keys, values):
...         self._keys, self._values = keys, values
...
>>> result = [Record(('key1_1', 'key1_2'), ('value1_1', 'value1_2')), Record(('key2_1', 'key2_2'), ('value2_1', 'value2_2'))]
>>> [dict(zip(r._keys, r._values)) for r in result]
[{'key1_1': 'value1_1', 'key1_2': 'value1_2'}, {'key2_1': 'value2_1', 'key2_2': 'value2_2'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know for sure if this works given that your example didn't mention any explicit inputs. But I suppose this should work:

```
 data = [dict(zip(r.__dict__['_keys'], r.__dict__['_values'])) for r in result]
```

This unpacks your keys and values in each of your subdicts.